# textbox text sets itself to null string

Tags: c#, textbox

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    powerTextBox.Text = "0";
    torqueTextBox.Text = "0";
    rpmTextBox.Text = "0";
}

private void powerTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    power = Convert.ToDouble(powerTextBox.Text);

    rpm = Convert.ToDouble(rpmTextBox.Text);

    torque = power / rpm * 9550;
    torqueTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(torque);
}
```

When i run this i get an error that says rpmTextBox.Text cannot be converted due to wrong format and at debugger it shows rpmTextBox.Text = "". I am assigning 0 as string to it inside initialize but it sets it to null string.

Any suggestion?
Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you set `powerTextBox.Text = "0";`? You raise the `TextChanged` event. The other TextBoxes Text is not set, thus their Text property is null. Then here: `torque = power / rpm * 9550;` you have a division by zero waiting to happen. The input must be validated. You cannot blindly parse anything that's passed in.

Comment: Consider setting a boolean at the end of the constructor - something like `finishedLoading`. Then in `powerTextBox_TextChanged` if `finishedLoading` is `false` then exit (no point validating, still loading the form).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Double.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8) method. Also rememeber that rpm shouldn't equal 0 (otherwise you will get [DivideByZeroException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dividebyzeroexception?view=netframework-4.8)):

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    powerTextBox.Text = "0";
    torqueTextBox.Text = "0";
    rpmTextBox.Text = "0";
}

private void powerTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Double.TryParse(powerTextBox.Text, out double power)
       && Double.TryParse(rpmTextBox.Text, out double rpm))
    {
       if(rpm != 0)
       {
          torque = power / rpm * 9550;
          torqueTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(torque);
       }
    }
    else
    {
       //Handle invalid inputs
       torqueTextBox.Text = "Wrong power or rpm";
    }
}
```